# How to use request/response with in node cron job

Tags: node.js, cron

Hi i am a beginner in node js. I need to use the cron to mail the user about the pending payment. I am using the module [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) . The url  */remainder* performs all the neccessary function to do the job and is working perfectly fine. My doubt is can I call this url within the cron job. How can we use the request/response. When the cron is run, the output is *null* .

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('00 * 23 * * *', function(req,res){
    console.log(req);


}, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: So for every request coming in to `/remainer`, you want to create a new CronJob and prints the request periodically?

Comment: You do not want to make your cron job functions available on an url. If a user finds the url, he/she can trigger the cron job as many times as he/she wants. It's better to call your function from inside your cron job. Just replace your console.log with a function or call a function in one of your controllers.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran No, i want to call the url /remainder periodically. but when i use res.writeHead(302, {  'Location': '/remainder'  }); it throws error because req is null.

Comment: @ThomasBormans Eventhough i need to use responses from queries

Comment: @AishwaryaKarthik What is the difference between visiting the url or calling the function directly? Are you doing stuff before/after visiting the url outside your function?

Comment: @ThomasBormans I already written the code for mail remainder , while we call the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `/remainder` is doing the actual job right? Just call it inside callback.

```
var request = require('request')
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('You will see this message every second');

    request('http://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('im ok')
            // console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
        }
    })
}, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```